# Splitting list in two new lists python

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

in Python I have a list with 96 entries, some are positiv, some are negative. I now want to new lists with 96 entries each. The first one should include all positiv values and instead of the negative values it should be 0 at this place in the list. The same the other way round for the second one. I think I have to use list-comprehension but don´t know how...

Thanks for help!

Comment: hint: you **never** *have* to use a comprehension

Comment: A list comprehension can only create one new list. Use a `for` loop and then `append` each element to the appropriate result list.

Comment: and how I will get 0 instead of the negativ value in this list...so i don´t want to short the list....the length of each list should be equal to the orginal one

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried and where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using list comprehensions and `... if ... else ...`:

```py
lst = range(-5, 5)

pos = [x if x > 0 else 0 for x in lst]
neg = [x if x < 0 else 0 for x in lst]

print(pos) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(neg) # [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Alternatively, using `for` loop:

```py
pos, neg = [], []
for x in lst:
    if x > 0:
        pos.append(x)
        neg.append(0)
    else:
        neg.append(x)
        pos.append(0)
```

Or, shorter:

```py
pos, neg = [], []
for x in lst:
    pos.append(max(x, 0))
    neg.append(min(x, 0))
```